# What exactly is ListView.RetrieveVirtualItem Event - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-3.5

With respect to a Virtual ListView control in a Winforms App, what are **ALL** the functions of RetrieveVirtualItem event?

Scenario: There is a Dictionary object which acts as my ListView cache. And its items are displayed on the ListView. On click of a column, the cache dictionary is sorted in memory and the ListView is Refresh()ed. The effect on UI, the ListView is sorted well. :)

But I want to understand what the role of RetrieveVirtualItem Event is, which gets triggered on Refresh().

In the RetrieveVirtualItem event handler [ Someone else's code, :( ], following are done:

1. Based on `RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs.ItemIndex`, get the message from Cache
2. Set `RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs.Item` = retreived item above

It appears that what's done in the event handler is important because, if I take it out, ListView cries. What is the significance of this event?

**EDIT**
Or let me re-phrase the question... My concern is, Why, after Sorting (and `RetrieveVirtualItem` event handler), the selected item remains at the location where it was before sorting. I.e, If I select item #5 and sort, and if sorting makes this item as the last item, I would prefer the LAST item to be selected after Sort. But in my case 5th item is selected after sort. So what is the default behavior of `RetrieveVirtualItem` WRT selected item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual listviews only deal with indices. So, if the 5th item is selected before the sort, the 5th item will still be selected after the sort. The control itself has no way of knowing that the data that used to be on the 5th row is now on the first row.

You will have to program that for yourself in your sorting method:

1. remember which items were selected (remember: you can't use `SelectedItems` property when in virtual mode)
2. do the sort
3. find the indices of the previously selected item now live
4. select those indices

You can see all this in action in [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) -- a wrapper around a standard .NET ListView.

Answer (score 4):

A virtual ListView should only call RetreiveVirtualItem for the rows currently visible on the screen.

As you navigate in the ListView, for example, you press the page down key, the ListView will calculate what should now be the index of the top row and will then call RetrieveVirtualItem so that your code can provide the item to use at each row index.

Unless you cache or otherwise store the items you are providing via RetrieveVirtualItem, they will no longer exist once they are scrolled out of the listview.

This is what the Virtual in VirtualListView means - there aren't any real rows, the rows are virtual.  That is how it could display a list containing hundreds of thousands of rows - because it will ever only actually contain how ever many rows are visible on screen.

In effect, the ListView is like a window that is moving up and down your internal list of data - the RetreiveVirtualItem method is what it calls to move items into that window as it moves along.  It says, hey I just moved to row 15 - give me the item for that row.  It will proceed to call RetreiveVirtualItem for each row index which would be visible.  If the ListView was 5 rows in height on the screen, you would receive 5 calls to RetrieveVirtualItem - even if the actual data backing the listview had 3000 items. Each time the top row of the ListView changed (because of navigation), you would receive 5 calls to RetrieveVirtualItem (this is not always the case, but it is the right idea - for example, if you scroll down one row, it will simply ask you for the new last row - it will also simply discard the data that was used for the old top row that scrolled out of view).

I guess it might be even easier to explain if we assume the ListView was only one row high on the display (meaning only a single row is ever actually visible on the screen) - as you move the ListView up and down your list of data (i.e. the user navigates the ListView), it would call RetrieveVirtualItem exactly one time every time it moves to a new row.

Hope that helps...
Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

The RetrieveVirtualItem event is only used when the ListView is put into virtual mode. Rather than retaining ListViewItems in the Items collection (as when not in virtual mode), it creates the ListViewItems dynamically, when needed.

If you don't handle the RetrieveVirtualItem event then no ListViewItems will be added to your ListView. I've attached some sample code for a typical method written to handle the event:

```
  //Dynamically returns a ListViewItem with the required properties; in this case, the square of the index.
void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if cache has been instantiated yet, and if so, whether the item corresponding to the index requested has been added to the cache already
        if (myCache != null && e.ItemIndex >= firstItem && e.ItemIndex < firstItem + myCache.Length)
        {
            //Return cached item for index
            e.Item = myCache[e.ItemIndex - firstItem];
        }
        else
        {
            //When item not in cache (or cache not available) return a new ListViewItem
            int x = e.ItemIndex * e.ItemIndex;
            e.Item = new ListViewItem(x.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This example is taken from MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) where further details can be found.

Comment: You said "If you don't handle the RetrieveVirtualItem event then no ListViewItems will be added to your ListView", so on the contrary, does it mean that ALL the items are added by this event? Seems no, because, it plays only with `myCache[e.ItemIndex - firstItem]`.

Comment: Yes, all items (when listview is in virtual mode) will be added by this event. The method doesn't only rely on fetching items from myCache as if the code within the else clause is executed a new item is instantiated and assigned to the event args (e.Item=new ListViewItem()). Another event CacheVirtualItems is relied on to manage the cache